# why uitabbaritem image does not show at first time?

Tags: ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I have create 4 items on uitabbar, all the images is 32 * 32 px, 150dpi.
when i run it, only the first icon is appear, the others are disappear.

[image]

[image]

but when i click the others or wait about 20 seconds they are appear.

[image]

and i found when i set the Storyboard Entry Point to this uitabbarviewcontroller the icons will be show, when i set Storyboard Entry Point to login uiviewcontroller, after login success, i jump to uitabbarviewcontroller the icons are disappear.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSuccess" sender:self];
```

why this happen?
please give me some help, thanks!

Comment: Did you create them in code or in a storyboard? If code, can you show it?

Comment: Hi Tim, just in a storyboard with UITabbarController.

Comment: And the icons are visible in Storyboard?

Comment: yes, i think so,I have add a picture.

Comment: @Tim, thanks for you help,  i have found why this now, they are in different thread.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!